# Symfony services container is imported but how?

Tags: php, symfony

I have to make modifications on a Symfony project and I am currently wondering how this project works.

It has a services.php file in Company/Bundle/Resources/config that manages the instantiation of services, but it is not imported anywhere...

I looked in app/config/config.yml, config_dev.yml, config_prod.yml, security.yml, etc and there are no imports for this file!

I know it used by the application, but I have no idea how it is imported :/.

Comment: Symfony uses the autoloader to autoload services. Check there first.

Comment: But all service configurations must be imported from inside the config.yml file in one way or another. I want to know how it is imported in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it make use of the DependenctInjection service? Have a look at the docs [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html#components-dependency-injection-loading-config)

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\PhpFileLoader;

$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$loader = new PhpFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__));
$loader->load('services.php');
```

This will autoload the service when the symfony app is initialized.

Comment: Indeed it does! But it uses those classes instead: use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Parameter;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\DefinitionDecorator;

Also in my file, it starts using the $container variable right away. I wonder where it is instanciated.

Comment: Ah it is instanciated in a class that extends Etension.

Comment: Glad that you found it.